# A default button to an entire webpage to respond to the ENTER key press

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to set a default button for the ENTER key press for an entire webpage?

I googled and I came across the below code. But I'm not sure of what this line means `var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));` So I thought of posting this question here at stackoverflow.

Thanks.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input").bind("keydown", function (event) {
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
            if (keycode == 13) {
                document.getElementById('btn').click();
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That particular line of code is just a cross-browser way to get the ID of the key that was pressed. `13` is Enter.

Comment: It's also way of determining what key was pressed across different physical devices. For example the enter key on my keyboard will be `keyCode 13`, but the enter key on a EAN Barcode reader might be `keyCode 0` but it has `charCode 13` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different browsers/devices<sup>1</sup> support different properties of obtaining key codes. The ternary expression is the same as:

```
var keyCode;

if(event.keyCode) // if keyCode is supported get that #top-priority
    keyCode = event.keyCode;

else if(event.which) // else, if .which is supported, get that
    keyCode = event.which;

else                 // alas! nothing above is supported
    keyCode = event.charCode; // we should take charCode
```

<sup>1 Devices for example EAN barcode reader has a `charCode of 13` Since its `.keyCode` is 0 (falsy), the 1st if condition is failed. [Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013324/a-default-button-to-an-entire-webpage-to-respond-to-the-enter-key-press/24013402#comment37011660_24013324) - [MLeFevre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1557617/mlefevre)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery (if an option) I would do

```
$(document).keyup(function(evt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
            // do your thing 
        }

}
```

This worked for me in Chrome,FF, Safari and Opera.
Also consider using various checks as in @Gaurang Tandon's answer to cover all hardware specs.

Comment: Some softkeyboards & other hardware do not use `evt.keyCode`, but do use `evt.charCode`

Comment: Useful.. I'll combine this and @Gaurang Tandon answer.